# Use SIFT in Python 3.6.4 in Mac OS X (AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d')

Tags: python, macos, opencv, computer-vision, opencv-contrib

My version of Python is 3.6.4
OpenCV version 3.4.0

I want to use the SIFT function in OpenCV, but I got stuck in the error below...
"AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'"

I know by searching that 'xfeatures2d' can be used by installing opencv_contrib. I did install it and apply it in Pycharm.

[Pycharm Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnAsW.png)

I can't figure out what is wrong...

Comment: Did you try gooling your problem?
 Look at the comment on http://answers.opencv.org/question/181047/python3-attributeerror-module-cv2cv2-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d/. If you installed twice, may be you also have two versions of cv2 on site-packages

Comment: Of course i did... and at last i solved the problem...

pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

in terminal solved my problem haha...
thank you for the comment